# Может поменять функцию кнопки "Пример кода"?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, форматирование

### Описание

Чем больше вопросов смотрю тем часто встречаюсь с таким кодом -

> [image]

[Вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1151489) уже отредактировали и исправили, но
дальнейшие случаи никто не отменил. Предлагаю, что всё это из-за этой кнопки...

> [image]

...который не смотря на размер кода ставит 4 пробелы. Конечно я не говорю что во всём этом виноват сообщество, а не участники, но помню когда был новичком так же задавал вопросы. :-)
Так что в целях облегчить не только новичкам и мне, но и всем остальным жизнь предлагаю, чтобы при нажатии данной кнопки появился следующий код:

````
```lang-
введите сюда код
```
````

либо просто

````
```
введите сюда код
```
````

---

### Вопрос

Что думаете?

Comment: это не поможет.

Comment: @Grundy почему не поможет? Если вставить код внутри, как ни крути она будет как код а не пол текст пол код. Не говорю что она ещё будет и красиво с отступами, но в некоторых случаях даже не надо будет редактировать вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

## Хорошая идея!

- С отступами будет проще.
- Многие (например я) используют ```
- Лучше видно где границы кода.
- Подсветка для не совсем стандартных языков (e.g. visual basic...):

Comment: подсветка синтаксиса определяется метками вопроса, а включить нужную можно специальным комментарием - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: @mymedia `lang-vb` — именно.